# Nginx : Installing Cacti - Adding a manual virtual host

Tags: nginx, cacti

I want to install Cacti to use on my server. The problem is that I added the location /cacti { .. in 000-ispconfig.vhost just like phpmyadmin, But I can't access it. Nginx returns error code 404.

Here is what I did till now:
`apt-get install cacti` and `apt-get install snmpd`

Then, I did `locate cacti` to see where the web script has gone. seems to be `/usr/share/cacti/site/`

I opened `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/000-ispconfig.vhost` and added a similar directive to phpmyadmin. I can access phpmyadmin and ispconfig itself. but not cacti.

```
location /cacti {
               root /usr/share/cacti/site/;
               index index.php index.html index.htm;
               location ~ ^/cacti/(.+\.php)$ {
                       try_files $uri =404;
                       root /usr/share/cacti/site/;
                       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock;
                       fastcgi_param  HTTPS on;
                       fastcgi_index index.php;
                       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
               }

        }
```

I think it has something to do with permissons.

Comment: What does `/var/log/nginx/error.log` say?

Comment: If you think it has something to do with permissions, why don't you check them?

Comment: @mgorven I didn't know error.log exist...Anyway: http://pastebin.com/WZ6AT54T Still I can't figure out what the error is trying to say. After setting directive in 000-ispconfig.vhost, I tried making a a custom vhost with listening port 80, still not working. Tried many ways and no luck. I don't want to use ISPConfig to manage this, Nginx should be able to run such script with this directive.

Comment: Can you please provide all the step you followed to fix the problem, in case someone else has the same error message?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/etc/cacti/debian.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/cacti/site/include/config.php on line 27
```

It looks like Cacti is failing because it can't load `/etc/cacti/debian.php`. Presumably this is supposed to contain some configuration, and I would expect the cacti package to create this. Debian bug [309194](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=309194) mentions a case where the webserver didn't have access to `debian.php`. Check that this file exists, and that the user which PHP runs as can read it.

Comment: I see! So that's why sometimes I was getting internal server error. It was actually running but with php errors being logged. Let me do some check on this debian.php file.

Comment: After going through a lot of test and trials, I managed to get it working. My directive used in Nginx was incorrect and debian.php should had correct permissions. Thanks a lot mgorven to helping me debugging this.